# Автогенерация имени

Tags: android, java

Есть сайт, к примеру `yandex.ru/2342342343453453453434534`

Tо, что в цифрах, всегда автоматически генерируется, когда заходишь на сайт. Как, используя `HttpClient` или `HttpUrlConnection`, получить сгенерированный адрес?

Я хочу всю историю в файл сохранить.

Comment: Вас уже давно по ip пора забанить.

Comment: очень неадекватные вопросы. В силу своей полной некомпетентности, вам кажется, что ваши вопросы адекватные.

Comment: Это xTigerX, что ли?

Comment: @Рамзес закончи школу сперва, а потом приступай учить программирование. Тем более Яву

Comment: @Expert, предлагаю для IP-адреса xTIGRx-оподобных пользователей делать автоматический редирект на google.com при посещении ХэшКода! XD

Comment: @Рамзес, как уже и говорили банят за неадекват. В последний раз забанили за мат. Там даже было предложение потестить правоохранителей на этот счёт. Жаль вопрос с комментами удалили сразу. Только вот скрин того непотребства у меня остался, если что)

Comment: Кажется, я пропустил какую-то важную драму (или это про .jobные файлы всё?)

Comment: Тогда попробуйте использовать не HttpClient, а WebView или подобный класс. Это обёртка для браузера, в ней также выполняется javascript и все редиректы. Позднее можно посмотреть текст страницы в WebView.

Answer (score 1):

[@Рамзес](/users/29765/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%81), ладно, помогу вам.

Если вы изначально посещаете страницу формата `http://te.st`, а потом в адресной строке вы обнаруживаете `http://te.st/420666228`, то и ежу понятно - сработал редирект. Чтобы с такими вещами работать, настройте ваш `DefaultHttpClient` (или другой наследник `HttpClient`, который вы используете), вызвав метод `.followRedirects(true)`. Ну и потом после выполнения запроса вытаскивайте `url`, на который вас перенаправили.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, Как мне получить sid ссылки, просто дело в том что когда я получил весь код сайта, там не было такой строки sid, какой я могу выдеть через браузер....Как быть тО?

Answer (score 0):

Этот адрес с цифрами на конце отправляется браузеру редиректом с сервера.
Так что используя HttpClient вы не столкнётесь с таким поведением.